# Heap corruption when VBA runs declared function but C++ console app runs ok?

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I'm using Visual C++ 2012 to make a wrapper function for making an API call from VBA.  If it matters, this is for the Bentley ProjectWise API, and I'm calling `aaApi_DocumentSelectDlg()`.

This function works when I run it from a C++ console app, but when I call it from VBA and step through the function, the API call results in a heap corruption error.

Here's the wrapper function:

```
//function for opening a file select dialog and getting the IDs associated with
//that file
long __stdcall FileOperator::selectFile(long* docArray)
{
 try
 {
  //set parameters for dialog
  AAOPENDOCSDLG2_PARAM param={0};
  param.ulMask |= AAOPENDLG2_MASK_FLAGS|AAOPENDLG2_MASK_TITLE|AAOPENDLG2_MASK_PROJECTID|
  AAOPENDLG2_MASK_DOCUMENTID|AAOPENDLG2_MASK_FILENAME;
  param.ulFlags = AAOPENDLG2_SINGLE_SELECTION | AAOPENDLG2_GET_IDS_ONLY | AAOPENDLG2_HIDEREADONLY | AAOPENDLG2_NO_USE_LASTPROJ;
  param.lpctstrTitle = L"Select a file";

  //open dialog, get result of user's selection
  long result=aaApi_DocumentSelectDlg(&param);

  //set array values to pass file info out of function
  if(result==IDOK)
  {
   docArray[0]=param.plProjectIds[0];
   docArray[1]=param.plDocumentIds[0];
  }
  else
  {
   docArray[0]=0;
   docArray[1]=0;
  }
  return 1;
 }
 catch (exception& e)
 {
  //error string not returned, just used for debugging
  string error=e.what();
  return 0;
 }
}
```

Here's the console app that executes successfully:

```
int main()
{
 //initialization function for opening session with database.  no problem here.
 long initResult=TestDLL::FileOperator::initialize("Test.QA.com:PWOPPID_XYZ");

 long selectResultArray[2]={0}; 
 TestDLL::FileOperator::selectFile(selectResultArray);

 return 0;
}
```

And here's the VBA code that causes the heap corruption:

```
Private Declare Function selectFile _
Lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bentley\ProjectWise\bin\TestDLL.dll" _
Alias "?selectFile@FileOperator@TestDLL@@SGJPAJ@Z" _
(ByRef docArray As Long) As Long

Public Function selectPWFolder() As Long

Dim docArray(1) As Long
Dim result As Long

docArray(0) = 0
docArray(1) = 0
result = selectFile(docArray(LBound(docArray)))
selectPWFolder = docArray(1)

End Function
```

I've narrowed it down to the API call by setting up the debugger so that it steps into the C++ code once the VBA calls `selectFile()`.  I did this by setting EXCEL.EXE as Debugging->Command, and C/C++->Browse Information->Enable Browse Information set to "Yes (/FR)".

What's puzzling is that the only element of the function that's different (or so it seems) when called from VBA is the `docArray` argument, which doesn't even get used by `selectFile()` until after the API call.  When I reach the `aaApi_DocumentSelectDlg()` line and step into it, I get the following error messages:

```
Critical error detected c0000374
EXCEL.EXE has triggered a breakpoint.
First-chance exception at 0x77E0E753 (ntdll.dll) in EXCEL.EXE: 0xC0000374: 
A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77E44270).
```

Why would VBA cause this heap corruption?  I'm passing a pointer to the first element of `docArray` so that I can pass the array from VBA to the DLL function without having to use SAFEARRAY, but I don't think that's the problem, because the call to `aaApi_DocumentSelectDlg()` doesn't use `docArray`.

EDIT: I made another version of `selectFile()` that does not accept any parameters, to test if the error occurs without `docArray`.  The heap corruption error still occurred.  So it has something to do with the API call itself and is unrelated to passing the array.

The code for the initialization function is:

```
long FileOperator::initialize(char* dbName)
    {
        LPCWSTR user=L"";
        LPCWSTR pwd=L"";
        LPCWSTR schema=L"";
        std::string dbNameStr=std::string(dbName);
        std::wstring sTemp=std::wstring(dbNameStr.begin(),dbNameStr.end());
        LPCWSTR dbName_L=sTemp.c_str();
        bool resultInit=aaApi_Initialize(AAMODULE_ALL);
        bool resultLogin=aaApi_Login(AAAPIDB_UNKNOWN,dbName_L,user,pwd,schema);
        if (resultInit&&resultLogin)
        {
            return 11;
        }
        else if (resultInit&&!resultLogin)
        {
            return 10;
        }
        else if ((!resultInit)&&resultLogin)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235591(v=vs.60).aspx) is a good resource on possible issues with calling an exported dll function from VBA. Does the error occur if you rewrite `selectFile` to accept no parameters _and_ immediately `return 0;`?  If that fails, I'd have to agree that it has to be the way the function is exported.

Comment: @Blackhawk, the heap corruption error does not occur if I rewrite it as you suggested: no parameters, the only statement in the function body is `return 0;`.

Comment: Here are some [common causes of heap corruption](http://www.efnetcpp.org/wiki/Heap_Corruption#Common_causes_of_heap_corruption).  I notice that in your code, the selectFile function is actually a member function of an object, FileOperator. In your C++ code, you run an initialization function - is something similar done in VBA?  Could be something where Excel (VBA VM) tries to close a FileOperator object that has already been closed?

Comment: Good idea.  I tried removing the initialization function from my VBA test, and the test ran without the heap corruption error.  However, the file dialog produced had no files in it, as the initialization function is necessary to open a connection to the database where the files are stored.  So it's probably some conflict between the values set during initialization and the tasks performed by `aaApi_DocumentSelectDlg()`.  Unfortunately I don't have access to the source code for the API, so this will be tricky to properly debug; any advice?

Comment: Can you add the code for the initialization function? (the code inside your wrapper dll function) It may be that the string you pass to the intialization might be getting modified or referenced in an unsafe way after the initialization function returns.  In VBA, strings are actually BSTRs.  When you pass a ByVal String to an API call, VBA automatically creates a temporary ASCII copy of the string and sends a pointer to that into the function.  As I understand, it is deallocated when the function returns. Perhaps thats the problem?

Comment: For reference, a BSTR is a UTF-16 string with a 4 byte length prefix and a 2 byte null postfix.  The string "Hello" would appear in memory as 16 bytes: `[0A 00 00 00] [48 00] [65 00] [6C 00] [6C 00] [6F 00] [00 00]`.  You will notice that the elements are stored in little endian - the Long length and each WChar.  It is important to note that the BSTR is stored as a pointer, but the pointer POINTS TO THE ADDRESS OF THE FIRST WCHAR, NOT THE LENGTH, even though the length comes first in memory.

Comment: @Blackhawk: I added the code for the initialization function.  The VBA code passes a ByVal string; I'll see if making that a ByRef makes a difference.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42540/discussion-between-blackhawk-and-sigil)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your VBA to:

```
Private Declare Function selectFile _
Lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Bentley\ProjectWise\bin\TestDLL.dll" _
Alias "?selectFile@FileOperator@TestDLL@@SGJPAJ@Z" _
(ByVal lpdocArray As Long) As Long

Public Function selectPWFolder() As Long

Dim docArray(1) As Long
Dim result As Long

docArray(0) = 0
docArray(1) = 0
result = selectFile(VarPtr(docArray(0)))
selectPWFolder = docArray(1)

End Function
```

This explicitly sends the function the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: I applied this change, but I still got the heap corruption error.  What's more, if I click "Continue" instead of "Break", I eventually get an "Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF" error, which I wasn't getting when using the `LBound()` approach.

Comment: Is it possible that your C++ Longs are 64-bit? VBA is ostensibly providing a two 32-bit slot array, so if the C++ code is writing two 64-bit values it would smash the stack.

Comment: I just checked, and `sizeof(long)` returns 4, so they're 32-bit, right?

Comment: also, I tested the code without the array, and I still get the heap corruption error (see my edit above).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing in an *array* of Longs to your DLL call, that looks like it is being altered by the call, I'm guessing it should be passed by address.
Declaring `(ByVal lpdocArray As Long)` passes in the contents of a 32-bit value.
I think you'd be better off with ByRef instead of ByVal - which will then automatically pass the address.

Now since you've used ByRef you should be able to just call with the variable identifier:
`result = selectFile(docArray)`

Comment: I tried it without passing the array, and still got the error.  It's something about how VBA handles this particular API call; various other functions in the same API don't cause this problem.

Comment: Check out this page:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/205277 . It talks about passing arrays from classic VB to a DLL. Turns out VB arrays start with housekeeping headers that you want to avoid. Their solution is no ByVal, no ByRef and call `selectFile(docArray(0))` without VarPtr. (altough I think an explicit ByRef might help)

Comment: As I stated above (in the EDIT: section), the API call is failing even when there are no parameters passed.  Thanks for doing the research on VB->DLL arrays, though; I'll need it for this function once I get the API call to work.